# How to get POST data for next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am writing a form validation program using the `App Router` in `Next.js`.

```js
// app/register/page.tsx
export default function Register(context: any) {
    console.log("Register page", context.params, context.searchParams);
    return (
        <form method={'POST'} action={'/register'} >
            <input name="usr"/>
            <input name="pwd"/>
            <button type={'submit'}>Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

I want to obtain the data passed in by the client through `POST`, but it seems that I can only obtain parameters on the URL using `context.searchParams` and `context.params`.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes#request-helpers The POST data is in `req.body`. You can check the method with `req.method`.

Comment: can you show your request handler? By convention, you should have an /api/register.tsx file that handles the POST on the server.

Comment: 1. I am using `app router` instead of `page router`, but the document you provided is for `page router`

2. Because I am using `app router`, when I access`/register `, the scope will be `app/register/page.tsx `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use[Router Handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing)

Example:

```
// app/test/route.ts

import {NextResponse} from 'next/server'

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const res = await request.json()
    console.log(request);
    console.log(res);
    return NextResponse.json({hello: 'world'})
}
```

You can use it in a browser `http://url/test` to access it